# IntelliJ IDEA can't get last version of dependence

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nd4j

I trying to import last version of `org.nd4j:nd4j-api:0.4-rc3.7`, but there is only `org.nd4j:nd4j-api:0.4-rc1.2`. So, how to add last version of nd4j?

Comment: Do you use maven too?

Comment: Yes. Everyone downvote me, but no one answer: reload pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>nd4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.4-rc3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure your maven has access to maven central.

Comment: Ok then, how to enable access to maven central?

Comment: configure it as repository in the `settings.xml` of maven (user-dir\.m2\settings.xml)